# Can Tree Transducers Self-Interpret?

Tags: programming-languages, interpreters, transducers

Is it possible for MSO graph/tree transducers to reflect themselves, namely to create an interpreter of tree/graph transducers using tree/graph transducers? If yes, I'll be happy for some design guidelines.

Comment: 1. Rather than modifying the question in a way that invalidates the answer to your original question, it's probably better to leave the original one and ask a new question....  2. How do you want the input tree transducer to be represented?  I suspect the answer might depend on the representation.  Presumably you want it to be represented as a tree somehow, but it's not clear to me what that might look like (a tree isn't exactly the most obvious representation for such a transducer).

Comment: will accept your answer and open a new question with a better desc of what i really want, thanks! what i really want is a language that can reason over itself, but having a complete logic. like mltt, but mltt isn't complete, it's decidability window is quite narrow

Comment: as for your second point, a transducer is trivially represented as a graph

Comment: So do you only want to ask the question about graph transducers?  Or do you still want to ask about tree transducers, too?  if so, how do you plan to address that, for tree transducers?

Comment: the question meant for either trees or graphs, not trees and graphs (and mso over graphs is reducible to mso over trees)

Comment: Your question appears to be asking at least two different questions: is there a way to create a tree transducer that acts as a compiler of tree transducers?  Is there a way to create a graph transducer that acts as a compiler of graph transducers?  My comment was about the former.  Your response was only about the latter, so it doesn't really respond to my comment.  Note that we have a guideline here: only one question per post.  This kind of back-and-forth is one good reason why we have that guideline.  Please ask a new question about compiling.

Comment: done http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62784/higher-order-verification-in-a-complete-logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in any straightforward way, because a tree transducer only accepts a single input, while an interpreter needs two inputs.

An interpreter needs *two* inputs: a transducer $R$ and a tree $T$, and would output the $R(T)$.  But a tree transducer can only accept *one* input.

Consequently, there appears to be no way to build such an interpreter (unless you accept some crazy way of pre-processing the inputs to bring them into a form that they can be provided to a tree transducer -- but it's hard to see how to define that in a way that rules out trivial solutions where it's the pre-processor that's actually doing all the interpreting).

Comment: sure, guess i need to rephrase the question. i still need to think how to write it correctly. in general, i'd like to implement (if possible) a programming language being basically MSO over graphs to interpret itself, where the language looks like prolog (kb and query).

Comment: another reformulation would be remaining the question as-is, just replacing "interpreter" with "compiler", to say assembly code