# Higher order verification in a complete logic

Tags: formal-languages, logic

I'd like to design a language that is able to reason over itseslf, means, able to get as input a code in that language (that might have went through some external redundant preprocessing, or "reflection" if to use another term) and reason over it. MLTT is of course a natural choice. But I'm seeking for a logically complete language, obviously sacrificing expressiveness (in fact it must not be able to express arithmetic, otherwise by Godel or more directly by the mortal matrix problem or Hilbert's 10th problem it cannot be complete). Therefore as first candidadte I thought of MSO over graphs. My question is how can MSO over graphs reason over itself, or more precisely, if we had a prolog-like (kb&query) language in MSO over graphs logic, how could it interpret or compile itself (and as a byproduct also reason over itseslf)?

Comment: What  completeness have you got in mind? If you have arithmetic in your language, Goedel's incompleteness theorem destroys completeness in the conventional sense. In program logic we are typically interested in *observational completeness*, which means that for all programs $P, Q$ it is the case that $P \cong Q$ exactly when for all pre and postconditions $A, B$ we have: $\{A\} P \{B\} $ iff $\{A\} Q \{B\} $. Here $\cong$ is the chosen notion of operational equality. In other words: observational completeness means that the logic makes the same distinctions as the operational semantics.

Comment: An even stronger form is *descriptive completeness*, which means that for every program $P$ you can find two formulae $A, B$ that completely describe $P$'s behaviour: in other words (simplifying a bit) we have (1) $\{A\} P \{B\}$, (2) for any $Q$, if $\{A\} Q \{B\}$ then already $P \cong Q$, and (3) the pair $A, B$ is the (logically) weakest pair that nails down $P$'s behaviour. Descriptive completeness implies observational completeness but not vice versa.

Comment: i'm interested in a powerful enough higher order representation, such that the language is able to interpret (or compile to some low level language) itself. once it is able to do so, and being a logical language that admits logical completeness, then every expressible statement would be decidable, for basically "all" possible expressible behaviors of the program, as the self-interpretation/compilation ability already decompose the input program to the "smallest" building blocks. of course descriptive completeness is implied, though i can't tell if vice versa. im still reading your paper though

Comment: (im having in mind Ong&Kobayashi HORS and the ability to reason over the execution tree in a complete manner, using MSOL over trees)

Comment: after reading more of your paper, i think descriptive completeness is indeed too much to ask for. nevertheless mso over graphs enjoy direct translation to automata which in turn can be minimized into a unique form. but this goes back to the original question: can mso over graphs express translation&minimzation of another mso over graphs predicate into automaton, and execute it vs some input graph?

Comment: In parts it depends on what exactly you mean by a language $L$representing itself. You can always represent programs in any language by strings or as ASTs. in $L$ Turing-completeness of $L$ means you can write interpreters and compilers for any language. If you have an observationally complete logic for $L$ you can reason about the compiler / interpreter. This is a consequence of Peano Arithmetic being expressive enough to represent computation. The downside of this approach is that you encode computation as numbers and that's cumbersome. You'll be drowning in encodings during reasoning.

Comment: So I guess you want a more direct representation of $L$ in $L$. Maybe by some (quasi-)quotation mechanism. Now we are in the realm of meta-programming. There is a [program logic for a meta-programming language](http://www.lmcs-online.org/ojs/viewarticle.php?id=1374&layout=abstract), but the language has relatively little expressive power for doing advanced meta-programming. Extending this to expressive meta-programming is an open research problem.

Comment: I don't know about MSOL.

Comment: the ultimate reference for msol over graphs is www.labri.fr/perso/courcell/Book/TheBook.pdf  for msol over trees can see tata.gforge.inria.fr neither are turing complete ofc

Comment: peano arithmetic is a very special case of msol over trees. please give a reference/explanation to your statement "If you have an observationally complete logic for LL you can reason about the compiler / interpreter. This is a consequence of Peano Arithmetic being expressive enough to represent computation." indeed a quatation mechanism sounds like what i look for (bearing in mind brown&paulsen self interpreter)

Comment: ah sorry peano is trivial. i misread it as presburger. and presburger is special case of msol over trees

Comment: theorems 29 and 30 here seem to give exactly what i was looking for http://logica.dmi.unisa.it/tacl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/LICS15-Higher-Order_Model_Checking.pdf

Comment: If you have a programming language $L$ that is Turing-complete, then you can write a compiler for language $L'$ in it, since you can write compilers using Turing machines. The compiler, like any program, is completely determined by its operations. Observational completeness of a program logic for $L$ simply means that the operations can be expressed and reasoned about without reservation in the program logic. (The argument goes through -- mutatis mutandis -- for interpreters too.)

Comment: In order to have an $L'$-compiler in $L$, you need to represent $L'$ programs in $L$. There are many ways of doing this, with numbers being Goedel's pioneering proposal (which comes from Leibniz), but numbers are rather inconvenient. If $L = L'$ then we can use (quasi-)quotation, meaning we use $L$-programs to represent $L$-code. In this case, we need a mechanism to distinguish $L$-programs from $L$-code. The Lisp tradition uses the backquote, MetaOCaml uses $\langle \cdot \rangle$, Scala's LMS tradition uses types.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "peano arithmetic is a very special case of msol over trees", since MSOL is decidable, unlike Peano.